# A code that works from the site side as I want, but it ruins the appearance of the control panel in the Blogger platform

Tags: html, css, header, blogger

The code is correct and has no errors

html

```
<header>
<div class="head">
<div class="wrap">
<b:section class='HeaderTop_MenuTop_Add_1Pages_2Socials column' id='HeaderUp_MenuUp_Add_1Pages_2Socials' maxwidgets='2' showaddelement='yes'>
<b:widget id='LinkList1' locked='false' title='1Pages' type='LinkList' version='1'>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

css

```
.head {
            
            }
#HeaderUp_MenuUp_Add_1Pages_2Socials {
                height: 51px;
            }
```

[The site header gives me what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmgCy.png)

[Then this problem appeared and I did not find a solution to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV7qQ.png)
[I want a code that fixes the header so that it does not ruin the appearance of the layout in the control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LApLS.png)

`

the problem is

```
/* custom head = HeaderTop_MenuTop_Add_1Pages_2Socials = 1pages + 2socials position */
            #HeaderUp_MenuUp_Add_1Pages_2Socials {
                height: 51px; /* fix layout in admin pannel before height: 51px; now height: none; */
            }
```

put the website header will disappear